# Какой частью речи является слово "уверена"?

Tags: морфология, части-речи

Помогите определить, какой частью речи является слово "уверена" в предложении:

**Все смеялись и подтрунивали над ним, а Оля была уверена: он своего добьётся.**

Это краткое прилагательное или краткое причастие? Я не чувствую здесь действия, но слово написано с одной буквой Н.

Answer (score 2):

> ***Все смеялись и подтрунивали над ним, а Оля была уверена: он своего добьётся.***

Я бы считал слово ***уверена*** в этом предложении прилагательным, написанным  с одним Н.

Из орфографического словаря на [**Грамоте.ру:**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x)

> **уверенный**; *кр. ф. прич.* -ен, -ена; **кр. ф. прил. -ен, -ена (*с дополн.*: она уверена в своей правоте)** и -ен, -енна (*без
>   дополн.*: она спокойна и уверенна; движения её уверенны)...

Дополнения к слову ***уверена***, правда, в приведённом Вами предложении нет — оно опущено, но при этом легко восстанавливается:

*...Оля была уверена (**в следующем**): он своего добьётся.*

Или:

*...Оля была уверена (**в том,** что) он своего добьётся.*

Comment: К сожалению, сейчас убегаю. К ночи вернусь,  постараюсь почётче изложить...

Answer (score 2):

Если исходить из того, что  прилагательное указывает на постоянный признак-качество, то это всё-таки прилагательное со значением "тверда в убеждениях", она сама уверенная, а не кто-то её уверил, здесь нет страдательности, нет действия. Видимо, чтобы отличить от такого случая употребления:Уверенная своим приятелем в правильности...  Она была уверена своим приятелем в том, что права...- здесь точно страдательное причастие.

Давайте сравним причастия и прилагательные на -имый. Если есть дополнение в творит. падеже - причастие и пишется с не раздельно, если дополнение в других падежах - прилагательное и пишется с не слитно: нелюбимый в семье - не любимый кем-то (или никем).

Наверное, здесь по такому же признаку, только пишутся и прилагательное, и причастие одинаково, с одной Н, возможно, чтобы отличить по смыслу два прилагательных: она была уверенна (решительна во всём) и она уверена в чём-то - какой-то переходный случай от прилагательного к причастию, что-то здесь осталось от действия, но возвратного (не сомневается).

Answer (score 1):

Все смеялись и подтрунивали над ним, а Оля была уверена (в чем): он своего добьётся.

1) Считается, что *уверена* –  краткое отглагольное прилагательное, пример разбирается у Розенталя: "В некоторых отглагольных прилагательных допускается двоякое написание в краткой форме в зависимости от значения и конструкции: при наличии зависимых слов пишется одно н, при отсутствии – два н, например:  Наши легкоатлеты уверены в победе. — Движения гимнастов легки и уверенны".

(В приведенном примере зависимое слово-дополнение заменяет предложение с изъяснительным значением, связь бессоюзная).

2) Конечно, с Розенталем не поспоришь, но мне кажется, что это скорее краткое причастие, образованное от глагола *увериться* с сильным управлением (этот глагол  требует обязательного наличия зависимого слова или прид. предложения).

УВЕРИТЬСЯ, св. в чём или с придат. дополнит. Убедиться, удостовериться в чём-л. У. в преданности друга.

Это причастие, так как оно выражает состояние, а не качественный признак, что видно из примера: она уверена (=точно знает) – движения уверенны (каковы?).

3) Как вы думаете, есть  ли основания для того, чтобы считать это слово причастием?